# libjai-imageio-core-java in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk, jdk

It seems that `libjai-imageio-core-java` is missing on 14.04 (it is available on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=imageio&searchon=names)):

Is there a replacement for this file? Or, how do I build from the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest binary build

```
cd
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jai-imageio-core/1.2-3/+build/3490005/+files/libjai-imageio-core-java_1.2-3_amd64.deb
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install libjai-core-java
sudo dpkg -i libjai-imageio-core-java_1.2-3_amd64.deb
```

---

Installed in Vivid:

```
% apt-cache policy libjai-imageio-core-java                                                                          
libjai-imageio-core-java:
  Installed: 1.2-3
  Candidate: 1.2-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.2-3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```